# How to create a program on python 3.5 where the user enters 10 integers

Tags: python, loops, integer

The user will enter 10 integers and in return the program will tell the user which is the largest odd integer of the 10 entered. I have pasted the script for my work below. The problem with my work is that when the largest number is even it returns with an error, how can i get python to ignore the largest even number and go on to the next largest odd number.

```
n1 = int(input('enter integer 1: '))
n2 = int(input('enter integer 2: '))
n3 = int(input('enter integer 3: '))
n4 = int(input('enter integer 4: '))
n5 = int(input('enter integer 5: '))
n6 = int(input('enter integer 6: '))
n7 = int(input('enter integer 7: '))
n8 = int(input('enter integer 8: '))
n9 = int(input('enter integer 9: '))
n10 = int(input('enter integer 10: '))

if n1%2!=0:
    a=n1
if n2%2!=0:
    b=n2
if n3%2!=0:
    c=n3
if n4%2!=0:
    d=n4
if n5%2!=0:
    e=n5
if n6%2!=0:
    f=n6
if n7%2!=0:
    g=n7
if n8%2!=0:
    h=n8
if n9%2!=0:
    i=n9
if n10%2!=0:
    j=n10

if n1>n2 and n1>n3 and n1>n4 and n1>n5 and n1>n6 and n1>n7 and n1>n8 and n1>n9 and n1>n10:
    print(n1, 'is the largest odd number')
if n2>n1 and n2>n3 and n2>n4 and n2>n5 and n2>n6 and n2>n7 and n2>n8 and n2>n9 and n2>n10:
    print(b, 'is the largest odd number')
if n3>n1 and n3>n2 and n3>n4 and n3>n5 and n3>n6 and n3>n7 and n3>n8 and n3>n9 and n3>n10:
    print(c, 'is the largest odd number')
if n4>n1 and n4>n2 and n4>n3 and n4>n5 and n4>n6 and n4>n7 and n4>n8 and n4>n9 and n4>n10:
    print(d, 'is the largest odd number')
if n5>n1 and n5>n2 and n5>n3 and n5>n4 and n5>n6 and n5>n7 and n5>n8 and n5>n9 and n5>n10:
    print(e, 'is the largest odd number')
if n6>n1 and n6>n2 and n6>n3 and n6>n4 and n6>n5 and n6>n7 and n6>n8 and n6>n9 and n6>n10:
    print(f, 'is the largest odd number')
if n7>n1 and n7>n2 and n7>n3 and n7>n4 and n7>n5 and n7>n6 and n7>n8 and n7>n9 and n7>n10:
    print(g, 'is the largest odd number')
if n8>n1 and n8>n2 and n8>n3 and n8>n4 and n8>n5 and n8>n6 and n8>n7 and n8>n9 and n8>n10:
    print(h, 'is the largest odd number')
if n9>n1 and n9>n2 and n9>n3 and n9>n4 and n9>n5 and n9>n6 and n9>n7 and n9>n8 and n9>n10:
    print(i, 'is the largest odd number')
if n10>n1 and n10>n2 and n10>n3 and n10>n4 and n10>n5 and n10>n6 and n10>n7 and n10>n8 and n10>n9:
    print(j, 'is the largest odd number')
```

Comment: *it returns with an error* - do we have to guess what error is reported or will you tell us?

Comment: Try reading up about lists and loops. They will make your programm a lot simpler

Answer (score 4):

I'm not completely sure what problem you're having and what error you're getting, but you should really look into using loops instead. Like this:

```
odd_numbers = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    input = int(input('enter integer {}: '.format(i)))
    if input % 2:
        odd_numbers.append(input)

if odd_numbers:
    print('{} is the largest odd number'.format(max(odd_numbers)))
else:
    print('There were no odd numbers entered')
```

*Normally I would have written this as a comment but wanted to help OP with how he can use loops*

Comment: Note: will raise a ValueError if there's no odd input.

Answer (score 0):

The first of many problems with your code is that `j` may not be defined when you try to print it.

Having said that, your code really needs refactoring. Look into lists, loops, generators and the `max` function. It is pretty pointless to start trying to fix your code.

Here's a suggestion for a concise version:

```
def max_odd():
    prompt = 'enter integer {}: '
    entered = (int(input(prompt.format(i+1))) for i in range(10))
    try:
        return max(x for x in entered if x%2)
    except ValueError: # no odd number
        return None
```

Demo:

```
>>> max_odd()
enter integer 1: 1
enter integer 2: 2
enter integer 3: 3
enter integer 4: 4
enter integer 5: 5
enter integer 6: 6
enter integer 7: 7
enter integer 8: 8
enter integer 9: 9
enter integer 10: 10
9
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing something like:

```
maximum=0 #Variable to store the maximum. Since this is even, if we get to the end of the program and it's still 0, we can be sure there were no odd numbers entered.
for i in range(1,11): #Loop from i=1 to i=10
    n=int(input 'enter integer: {}'.format(i)) #Ask for an integer input
    if (n%2) != 0: #If the number is odd
        if maximum==0 or n>maximum: #Then if it is bigger than the old maximum or it's the first odd number
            maximum=n #Then set it as the new maximum
if (maximum != 0): #If any odd numbers were entered
    print(maximum, ' is the largest odd number') #Output the biggest
else: #If none of the numbers were odd
    print('all input numbers were even') #Then complain
```